# C# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization

I have looked for a pointer on this a lot but haven't found a relevant Q/A

So I am adding a new property to a `Serializable` class that looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableClass
{
    public ExistingClass1[] property1;
    public ExistingClass2[] property2;
    // New property
    public NewType[] property3;
}
```

The new property will be of a type that I define like this:

```
[Serializable]
public struct NewType
{
    public string prop1;
    public string prop2;
}
```

So far everything is okay but during testing I found out that some of the older versions of our client tools stopped working. They started throwing the exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=21.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryConverter.TypeFromInfo(BinaryTypeEnum binaryTypeEnum, Object typeInformation, ObjectReader objectReader, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, InternalPrimitiveTypeE& primitiveTypeEnum, String& typeString, Type& type, Boolean& isVariant)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadArray(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)

Interestingly, this only happens when it tries to deserialize an object that has the new property but otherwise the old clients don't complain.

our deserializer looks like this:

```
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
        using (MemoryStream r = new MemoryStream(bits))
        {
            return formatter.Deserialize(r);
        }
```

As you can see we unfortunately use DotNet Binary Serializer/Deserializer.

Is there any workaround here ?
Is it better to use List instead ?

Comment: Well... do the tools that are failing have a reference to MyAssembly, and is it in the build output? But: ultimately, BinaryFormatter is just going to keep causing you pain, not least: moving to .NET 5 and above; literally any other serializer would be an improvement

Comment: Thanks Marc, the tools do have a proper reference of MyAssembly and thats how they work all the time except when they encounter an object with NewType. I completely agree with you on BinarySerializer but that is something I cannot change at the moment.

Comment: I doubt that list vs array would matter at all here; this is... unusual, even for BinaryFormatter - but virtually impossible to debug without a running repro; sorry

Comment: hmm yeah but setting up a repro in this case is a challenge in itself.

Comment: on the plus side: that's evidence for the costs that BinaryFormatter are causing you which should count towards prioritizing changing that to use something else

Comment: Did any assembly version change? You can try to set the `Binder` property and see in the `BindToType` method what assembly identities are used. [Here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/master/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/Serialization/Binary/WeakAssemblySerializationBinder.cs) is an example implementation (originally for [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#binary-serialization) serializer but works also for `BinaryFormatter`). But as Marc mentioned, binary serialization is maybe not the best practice for this purpose.

Comment: yeah but its futile trying convince the management about the toil when the system is legacy and has no real future.

Comment: Thanks Gyorgy, the version do change. The tools are at 20.1 and with my change we are now at 21.7. But why do they only complain when the deserializing object has new property ?

Comment: @epsilon: Such examples for `BinaryFormatter` behavior are still often mysterious to me, even after creating a fully functional replacement and tons of comparison tests. And `FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple` also behaves awkwardly: if the assembly is not loaded yet, then it might work but may throw an exception if there is a version mismatch with an already loaded assembly. Did you try to use a binder?

Comment: No I am not using binder.

Answer (score 1):

So after spending a really long time I have come to the conclusion that Binder is the only workaround but even this is not foolproof and would work only if you are lucky.

For my scenario, even custom binder is not a solution because one of the tools calls some APIs that return a blob which is deserialized by the tool. For other calls where deserialization occurs on the service side, things are fine using binder.

Here is [the link](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/24992/serialization-binder) I followed other than existing SO answers on BinaryFormatter and binders. This works partially for me as stated above but worth mentioning.

Thanks everyone who tried to help, cheers!